# Tomcat6 jk-8009 service using 100% CPU

Tags: mysql, jsf, tomcat, ajp

I have a problem with tomcat6, when I "top -H", I can see 3 java threads running at 100% CPU.
I looked up what tomcat was doing using PSI-probe and in the "Connectors" tab, under jk-8009, I can see the following 3 lines:

Remote IP   stage   Proc.time   IN  OUT     URL
192.168.10.11   Service     20:02:17.105    522 B   0 B     POST /configuration.jsf
192.168.10.11   Service     20:02:17.171    447 B   0 B     POST /configuration.jsf
192.168.10.11   Service     20:02:17.167    447 B   0 B     POST /configuration.jsf

According to the top command, the 3 processes which are at 100% have been running for 1197 minutes, which seem to correspond to the 20:02 minutes displayed in the 3 lines above. So I am pretty sure that these 3 services are the problem.

the /configuration.jsf which is stated is the main page of the application, so it could be anything.

Restarting tomcat solves the issue, but I need to find out what is the cause of the problem.

I can see no crash in the logs.
I looked around on the internet and it seems to me like it could be a deadlock in the database.

The application uses JSF, Prime Faces.
The database is mysql

Would anybody have any kind of input on the matter?

Edit:

in /etc/tomcat6/server.xml, I have this configuration

```
    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: I have a very similar problem going on currently. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am trying this
`<Connector port="8009"
               enableLookups="false"
               redirectPort="8443"
               protocol="AJP/1.3"
               maxThreads="50"
               minSpareThreads="5"
               maxSpareThreads="20"
               acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="2000"/>` 
Setting a timeout might solve the problem. But I can't say if it works, I did not have the problem since, but it is not somethign I can reproduce on demand.

Comment: I've tried that, does not help in my case.

Comment: I had it happening on a different server. I did added a timeout and change the protocol this way: 
<Connector port="8009"
               enableLookups="false"
               redirectPort="8443"
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol"
               connectionTimeout="2000"
               keepAliveTimeout="2000" />
 And it works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the blocking Java connector solved this for me in Tomcat 8.0.21:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Now CPU stays at about 0,3% when there is no usage. Using `AjpNio2Protocol` gave the same result with CPU but in my peformance test `AjpProtocol` was a bit faster.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/ajp.html#Connector_Comparison

Comment: I had it happening on a different server. I did added a timeout and change the protocol this way: <Connector port="8009" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol" connectionTimeout="2000" keepAliveTimeout="2000" /> And it works fine now